# OSINT: Geolocation to IP range

Tags: ip, geolocation

Usually, in OSINT when it comes to IP addresses and geolocation the investigator attempts to get a rough location from a public IP address. However, I'm trying to find out more about reversing that process. Let's say in this scenario I know the location of the entity of interest, to about the city level. Obviously you can't get an exact IP, just the range of IPs for that location. What tools are there I can use to find out an IP block of a location?

Comment: That isn't how IP address assignment works.  IP blocks are assigned to organizations, not geographic areas, so addresses from many IP blocks are going to exists in an area of that size, and IP addresses from those blocks will also exist in other geographic areas.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't.

IP addresses are assigned to organizations, not regions.  Those organizations may in turn assign address blocks to specific regions, but some don't.  The steps for figuring out what IP address your target might have would go something like this:

1. Figure out which ISPs operate in the area
2. Figure out which IP address ranges have been assigned to each of those ISPs.
3. For each address, do a lookup in your geolocation database to see if it's in the city of interest.

Note that because you're doing many lookups, the uncertainty inherent in geolocation is magnified.  Additionally, your target may be using an ISP that doesn't do geographic assignment (eg. satellite internet), or may be using an ISP not on your list.